# Is there any way to fetch images with date specified and display according to date in django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a e-newspaper app with django. I which i upload data in pdf format with date and convert the data to JPEG and save the to folder with the date specified format. I am trying to get the images for date specified only (images with particular date will be displayed on that date only ).But having no better luck with fetching the particular data.

models.py

```
class City(models.Model):
    cityid =models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField( max_length=50)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("City")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Cities")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class DailyFeed(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date =models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    files    = models.FileField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
def create_dailyfeed(request):
    folder='date/'
    image = 'images'
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        #Get All Files 
        files = request.FILES.getlist('files')
        form = DailyFeedForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            inst = form.save(commit=False)
            # Add Date DAte
            date = inst.date
            #Add City DATA
            city = inst.city.name
            # Date Data
            date1 = date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
            folder1 =   '{}/{}/{}'.format(folder,city,date1)
            fs = FileSystemStorage(location=folder1)
            media =  '{}/{}/{}'.format(image,city,date1)
            fs1 = FileSystemStorage(location = media)
            for f in files:
                filename = fs.save(f.name, f)
                file_url = fs.url(filename)
                filename1 = fs1.save(f.name, f)
                file_url1 = fs1.url(filename)
                #media FIle DIrectory

                #COnvert to JPG
                pages = convert_from_path('{}/{}'.format(folder1,f.name), 200)
                for page in pages:

                        page.save('{}/{}.jpg'.format(media,f.name[:-4]), 'JPEG')
            inst.save()
            return redirect('/', messages.success(request, 'Paper is successfully created.', 'alert-success'))
        else:
            return HttpResponse(form.errors)
    else:
        form = DailyFeedForm()
        return render(request,'newspaper.htm',{'form' : form})


#this is where i trying to fetch data     
def city(request):
    city_list = City.objects.all()
    date = timezone.now()
    date1 = date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
    image = 'images'
    akola =  '{}/Akola/{}/page01.jpg'.format(image,date1)
    washim = '{}/Washim/{}/page01.jpg'.format(image,date1)
    amravati = '{}/Amravati/{}/page01.jpg'.format(image,date1)
    khamgaon = '{}/Khamgaon/{}/page01.jpg'.format(image,date1)

    return render (request,'main.html',{'city_list':city_list,'akola':akola,'washim':washim,'khamgaon':khamgaon,'amravati':amravati})
```

HTML

```
<img src="{{washim}}" alt="">
```

I have also tried static files but having issue in specifying date and city name in it. 
if there any other way please suggest.

Comment: Check in your browser the URL it's trying to fetch (the value of `{{ washim }}`). Then check in your file system where the file is actually located.

Comment: Two things I don't get: 1. You can't save multiple files to one `DailyFeed` instance. You need to create one instance for each file (`FileField` can only hold one file). 2. If you fetch a `DailyFeed` instance (`daily = DailyFeed.objects.filter(city=city).first()` for example), then you can just display the file with `<img src="{{ daily.files.url }}">`.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank You For your help. But I want to archive data by date on which it is specified. (like if daily.date = 09/04/2020 then the data will be available on that date only) i little bit confused with queryset. can you please help ?

Comment: You're saving the date in `DailyFeed`, so you can filter by date: `DailyFeed.objects.filter(date=timezone.now().date())` to get all articles with the date of today.

Comment: Note also that you can automatically save the files in the dated folder using the `upload_to` callable as explained in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

Comment: Sorry but how can i save file with future dates ? In docs there is only today's upload date will automatically gets created

Comment: look at the callable example where the upload location depends on the user